# Parse data of repeating 4 line groups

Tags: perl

I have data that looks like this

```
02/06/2014  

VONS STORE
-$5.95

02/06/2014  

VONS STORE
-$3.99

02/06/2014  

VONS STORE
-$3.70

02/05/2014  

VONS STORE
-$8.99

02/05/2014  

VONS STORE
-$6.97

02/04/2014  

MISSION HI
-$5.74

02/03/2014  

R K SUSHI
-$34.23

01/30/2014  

MISSION HI
-$9.94
```

How could I separate this into data that looks like this:

```
VONS STORE (5x): $29.6
MISSION HI (2x): $15.68
R K SUSHI  (1x): $34.23
```

This needs to be done without prior knowledge of the store(s) or the order.

In reality, the only difficult part in this question is splitting the data into blocks of four lines – how can I do that?

Comment: If you know how to [read one line from a file](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html), all that's left is to read more than one line at a time (until [eof](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html)), then parse and track data using hashes or hashrefs keyed by store name. Is there a particular part of that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you or explain to you how to write the code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differed from the expected results, and any error messages you received. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the file one line at a time, and keep track of the last 4 lines read in a buffer, then flush:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.14;

open(IN, "<", "mydata.txt");

my @lineBuffer = ();
my %prices;
my %number;
while (<IN>) {
    chomp();
    if (@lineBuffer < 4) {
        push(@lineBuffer, $_);
    } else {
        my $price = @lineBuffer[3];
        $price =~ s/-\$//; 
        $prices{@lineBuffer[2]} += $price;
        $number{@lineBuffer[2]}++;
        @lineBuffer = ();
    }
}

for my $key (keys %number) {
    say $key." (".$number{$key}."x): ".'$'.$prices{$key}
}

close(IN);
```

Comment: The OP shows the results in descending order of number of sales.

Comment: Yep, and they're also formatted, but I figure he can take it from here.  He also asked specifically how to read in lines 4 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw/sum/;

local $/ = '';
my %h;

while (<>) {
    next if $. % 2;
    push @{ $h{$1} }, $2 if /(.+)\n-?\$(.+)/;
}

print "$_ (" . @{ $h{$_} } . 'x): $' . ( sum @{ $h{$_} } ), "\n"
  for sort { @{ $h{$b} } <=> @{ $h{$a} } } keys %h;
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

Output on your dataset:

```
VONS STORE (5x): $29.6
MISSION HI (2x): $15.68
R K SUSHI (1x): $34.23
```

Since there are blank lines, reading in paragraph mode (`$/ = ''`) is set.  Only even numbered paragraphs are processed, by capturing the business name and amount. A hash of arrays (HoA) is used, where the keys are the business names and the associated values are references to lists of amounts.

The results are `sort`ed and `print`ed, in descending order, by the number of amounts.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The first capture matches names, second matches the amounts, hash them up and print

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(IN, "<", "data.txt");
my %r;
my %t;
my $data = join "",(<IN>);

while( $data =~ /^([^\n\d]+)\n.*?^(-?)\$([\.\d]+)/img) {
  $r{$1}++;
  $t{$1} += $3;
}

foreach (keys %r){ 
   my $o = sprintf("%-15.15s(%dx): \$%02.2f",$_,$r{$_},$t{$_}); 
   print "$o\n"; 
}
```

Comment: How is the output sorted as the OP has it?